# VSTO - ClickOnce - certificates

Tags: certificate, vsto, clickonce

VSTO ClickOnce wants to add a certificate to the published client deployable.  Is there anything wrong with using a test certificate for this even in a Live environment - note we are on an Intranet (and hence trust isn't really an issue).

If we use a Test cert. in Live will it ever expire - if so, can we make it *not* expire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For intranet you can create your own code signing certificate by setting up microsoft certificate server or use makecert.

With this approach you can create a certificate with 10-20 year of validity and use certmgr to register. This new certificate can be used in visual studio to sign your project.